# Magento Catalog Price Rule not calculating properly for some products

Tags: magento

One order has an issue during our Black friday promotion (Catalog price rule 20%). The product original price is $198 but went through for $167 (around 15.6%). I checked the logs, order details etc but don't see any issues. The sale price is fine on front end and other orders were fine too.

Any thoughts how it happened? We are using Magento ver. 1.9.3.2.

[Product order amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti6uS.png)

[Product original amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USHLD.png)

The sale amount should have been $158.4

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the rule which was applied is different. Please see the rule details assigned to the corresponding order.

You can see the rule by running the below SQL.

```
SELECT applied_rule_ids FROM sales_flat_order WHERE entity_id=[MAGNETO_ORDER_ID]
```

And then see the rule details corresponding to that applied_rule_id

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked but its null though. "applied_rule_ids": null, . There was only 1 active Catalog price rule that time and no active shopping cart rule